# Movement of accelerating points with maximum speed (i.e. running away from tiger)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, time, acceleration, velocity

> I'm walking through a forest and suddenly I see a tiger. And now I have a problem. I want to know how much time I have left but I don't know how to calculate it.
>
> Or more formally:
>
> Let's say there are two points (A and B) with distance $s$ between them. Point A starts accelerating with $a_1$ until it reaches maximum speed $v_1$. Point B start accelerating with $a_2$ until it reaches maximum speed $v_2$. All velocities and accelerations have the same direction.
>
> I want to find out if and when these two points "meet".

I tried to spread it to several steps:

1. both points are accelerating until one reaches max speed
2. one point is accelerating and one is moving with constant speed
3. both points are moving at constant speed

But it gets messy quickly.

Comment: Hello David, even if this is not your homework, this is a homework type question. You should add the tag and check the FAQ on homework question.

Comment: As long as the tiger's terminal velocity is larger than yours, you will always end up as his lunch. Your approach is correct - write the equations of motion and solve for equality. Since the equations are piece wise continuous you can't get away without it being "messy" as you have to treat the different cases. But the end result (if you will be caught) is simple enough - the time takes effort. Not sure you want to spend you last moments on earth that way...?!

Comment: @Floris could you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth drawing a diagram:

[image]

The equations of motion are:

$$x_1 = x_0 + \frac12 a_1 t^2$$

for $t_1 < \frac{v_1}{ a_1}$

And

$$x_1 = x_0 + \frac{v_1^2}{2 a_1} + v_1 (t - \frac{v_1}{a_1})$$

for the steady state. The same equations, with different suffixes, hold for the tiger.

To solve, you start by considering all different orders of $t_1, t_2, t_3$ - a total of 6 different cases. But a couple of cases give the same solution so they can be grouped together. We end up having distinct solutions for

1. Both are still accelerating: $t_3 < t_1, t_2$
2. You are still accelerating: $t_1 < t_3 < t_2$
3. Tiger is still accelerating: $t_2 < t_3 < t_1$
4. Caught in steady state: $t3 > t_1, t_2$ (as diagram).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here are is my solution. I'll be happy is someone can provide something simpler.

$a_1, v_1, t_1 - acceleratin, terminal\ velocity,\ time\ to\ reach\ it\ (for\ Tiger)$
$a_2, v_2, t_2 - acceleratin, terminal\ velocity,\ time\ to\ reach\ it\ (for\ You)$
$s_0 - starting\ distance$

Not let's consider three cases:
1) $a_1 < a_2 \wedge v_1 < v_2$
You'll live (for now). Tiger can't catch you.

2) $a_1 > a_2 \wedge v_1 < v_2$
Tiger can catch you but only for limited time.
a) $t_1 > t_2$
Can't happen. Tiger has bigger acceleration and lower terminal velocity so he has lower "time to max".
b) $t_1 < t_2$
$$\frac{1}{2}a_1t^2 + \frac{1}{2}a_2t^2 = s_0$$
$$t = \sqrt{\frac{2s_0}{a_1+a_2}},\ a_1+a_2 > 0$$
Then we check $t < t_1$.

3) $a_1 > a_2 \wedge v_1 > v_2$
This splits to two cases a)  $t_1 < t_2$  b) $t_1 > t_2$
They're almost identical so I'll write here just a).
a) $t_1 < t_2$
$$t_3 = \sqrt{\frac{2s_0}{a_1+a_2}}$$
If $t_3 < t_1$ then this is solution.
Otherwise we continue checking various situasions as described in question. I'll show basic formulas that (I think) should be used for this.
$$s_1 = s_0 + a_2t_2-a_1t_1$$
$$s_2 = s_1 + a_2(t_2-t_1)-v_1(t_2-t_1)$$
$$v_1t-v_2t =s_2$$